# Delete Div and get Hidden field value - best approach

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below HTML sample

```
<div id="TestDiv_0">
  <input id="hf_0" type="hidden" value="0">
  <span class="checkBox checked">
</div>
<div id="TestDiv_1">
  <input id="hf_1" type="hidden" value="10">
  <span class="checkBox checked">
</div>
<div id="TestDiv_2">
  <input id="hf_2" type="hidden" value="23">
  <span class="checkBox">
</div>
```

Dynamic HTML and may grow

Am trying to implement few logic using JQUERY.

The scenario is **if span has class checked**.i need to implement 2 things

1. Get the **type="hidden" value** in Comma Seprated field(If multiple span is checked). Eg: in above HTML i need to get 0,10 in a variable
2. Remove the particular Div. Eg: in above HTML i need to remove TestDiv_0,TestDiv_1.

What is the best way to implement this? I tried getting the count of div and looping it through to find class and removed Div. But thought there will be some better ways.

Comment: Paste your javascript code as well.

Comment: Your HTML is missing closing span tags on all your spans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var arr = $('span.checked').map(function(){
     var id = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val(); 
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
     return id;
}).get().join(',');
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/pEnDY/

Comment: I like your approach, but may I ask what is `.get()` doing and why it won't work without it?

Comment: from http://api.jquery.com/get/: Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.   it selects and returns the dom element

Comment: called `.get()` to get plain array from jquery object returned by `.map()` and joined that array with `.join(',')`

Comment: @pXL, elegant, concise solution. +1.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H3EhF/2/)

```
var checkedItems=[];
function handleChecked(){
    $("span.checked").each(function(){
        checkedItems.push($(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val());
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    console.log(checkedItems);
}
handleChecked();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var values = [];

// get all spans with class 'checked'
$('div > span.checked').each(function() {

    // get the hidden field value
    values.push($(this).prev('[type="hidden"]').val();

    // remove the div containing this span
    $(this).parent().remove();

});

// get comma separated values
values = values.join(',');
```